# Trust relationship not working

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, active-directory

I have 2 environments with 2 different domain. Let one be a.com and second one be b.com. A trust exists between these domains such like b.com trusts a.com domain (external incoming request). This trust is setup so that a.com users or service accounts can be used in b.com domain too.

And in sites and services I can validate both the domains successfully, that is validating b.com from a and a.com from b is successful. But I can't use any of the user accounts of a.com to login or service accounts of a.com in b.com domain machines.

I can choose the a.com domain for finding a particular username from b.com machines, but can't find the username which exists. Finding results in this error:

[image]

What is the mistake I am doing here?

Comment: Can you post your trust configuration `netdom trust` from both sides? Can you post your DNS configuration between the two environments?

Comment: @MDMarra: Iam using windows server 2003 R2. and when executing netdom it throws error "netdom is not recognized as an internal command". I guess netdom is used in 2008 servers

Comment: Mainstream support for Server 2003 ended 4 years ago, and extended support ends next year. You should strongly consider upgrading. Finding people who remember how to diagnose decade old software is going to be hard.

Comment: Netdom is included in the 2003 admin pack. If you haven't installed it on your legacy 2003 servers, you should.